# How to remove the gray bar from the bottom of page in blogger?

Tags: blogger

Every page of my website has a gray bar at the bottom. It does not appear on Label page. I have tried all post-footer settings but can't get rid of it. help appreciated.  My website is www.tutorhubllc.com
Thanks

I have searched the internet. Haven't found a resolution.

Comment: Please post some of the code you have already tried out in order to fix the issue? What kind of errors, if any, were you observing?

Comment: .post-footer { margin: 0px;
  line-height: 0px;
}

Comment: and .post-footer
{
display: none;
}    neither of them worked. I am not exactly sure what part of the layout is the gray bar. It is post-footer or something else.   Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order yo do that, You have to remove padding from `#comment` element on blog pages. Use the following condition to target blog pages, Place this before `</head>`

```
<b:if cond='data:view.isPage'>
   <style> #comments { padding: 0 } </style>
</b:if>
```